# How to change color of the rating star using ngClass

Tags: angular

I am using RatingModule from 'ngx-bootstrap'. Initially the star color should be black.When I choose 1 star then the star color should be red
2 Stars -Blue
3 Stars-Yellow
4 Stars -pink
5 Stars-Green
I don't how to achieve this using ngClass.The below code is not working.I have initialized the ratingValue as 0

```
  max=5;//Five stars will be displayed
     <rating formControlName="ratingValue" [max]="max" ></rating>
```

I added this ngClass in above but it didn't work.

```
[ngClass]="{'black':ratingValue==0,'red':ratingValue==1,'red':ratingValue==2,'red':ratingValue==3,'red':ratingValue==4,'red':ratingValue==5}"

.pink{
color:pink;
}
.red{
color:red;
}
.yellow{
color:yellow;
}
.blue{
color:blue;
}
.green{
color:green;
}
.black{
color:black;
}
```

Comment: Is the class not being applied, or is the CSS that's not working?

Comment: did you log `ratingValue`?

Answer (score 1):

you probably need to access *ratingValue.value* to get the current value of the formControl.

Then use ngClass like you did in your example:

```
[ngClass]="{'black':ratingValue==0,'red':ratingValue==1,'blue':ratingValue==2,'yellow':ratingValue==3,'pink':ratingValue==4,'green':ratingValue==5}">
```

or even better (looks cleaner) pass a function to the ts file:

```
[ngClass]="getStarColorCSSClass(ratingValue.value)"
```

and in the TS file:

```
  getStarColorCSSClass(value: number): string {
    switch(value) {
      case 0:
        return 'black';
      case 1:
        return 'red';
      case 2:
        return 'blue';
      case 3:
        return 'yellow'
      case 4:
        return 'pink';
      default:
        return 'green';
    }
  }
}
```

If your CSS classes are only created for setting the 'color' property,
we can also avoid to create them by using ngStyle instead of ngClass (with the function above):

```
[ngStyle]="{color: getStarColorCSSClass(ratingValue.value)}"
```